# How do I keep a mesh selected as I add thousands of unique hairs to it?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, hair

I am trying to create a program that takes numbers from a .csv file and creates randomly placed hairs on a mesh called 'skin' with lengths dictated by those values.

So far, I'm finding it difficult to get started because it seems I cannot keep the mesh selected. I think what happens is that whenever the loop is run, the new hair becomes selected instead of the mesh.

I thought I could fix it by writing a line that selects skin just before the hair is placed, but it is still not working.

```
for l in hair_lengths:
    l = float(l[0])*(1/1000)                                 #divide to mm
custom_loc = random_xy()
bpy.context.scene.objects["skin"].select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.curves_empty_hair_add(align='WORLD', location=custom_loc, scale=(1, 1, l))
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated, I'm definitely open to alternate ways of approaching this.
`

Comment: Perhaps your object needs to be set "active" `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['skin']`

Comment: Can you fix the indent of the loop? It looks like you're trying to create one "empty hair" object (Curves object) for each hair particle. It doesn't work this way. You need to create only one Curves object and add the hair curves to this object. The hair curves (splines) have several control points, each with a position (x,y,z). You can see them in the Geometry Nodes Spreadsheet. I don't think that you can simply use a length value to create hair curves.

Comment: I think it's not possible yet. According to this development task [T68981](https://developer.blender.org/T68981), the *Python API > Add/remove curves and points* is not finished yet. It seems that there is currently no way to add curves and points to the [hair_curves](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData.hair_curves) object.